# Nginx proxy_hide_header not worked at a field included whitespace

Tags: nginx

I have a proxy with nginx for a upstream.The upstream will return a invalid header :"Time : Tue Oct 18 11:24:50 CST 2022",
This is the response headers.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.21.0
Date: Sat, 01 Apr 2023 16:47:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Time : Tue Oct 18 11:24:50 CST 2022
```

I need to remove the "Time " header.

```
location / {
   proxy_hide_header "Time ";
   proxy_pass server...;
}
```

But it dose not work.

Comment: can you try: 

```location / {
   proxy_ignore_headers Time;
   proxy_pass server...;
}```

Comment: that won't work

Comment: can you tell me how you test the configuration please ?